# Custom tag that creates select element from enum

Tags: java, tags, playframework

How can I make a tag that makes a select field out of a Java enum for the Play! framework?  I've tried to see how the CRUD module does it but there's too many abstraction layers that I don't really understand yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you fully qualify the Enum in the tag then you don't need to place it in RenderArgs.

Your tag StatusSelect.html:

```
<select name="status">
    #{list com.something.StatusEnum.values(), as:'status'}
        <option>${status}</option>
    #{/list}
</select>
```

And called from the page:

```
#{StatusSelect /}
```

You could then add complexity to it by specifying a "name" attribute and other features eg:

```
<select id="${_id}" name="${_name}" class="${_class}">
    #{list com.something.StatusEnum.values(), as:'status'}
        <option>${status}</option>
    #{/list}
</select>
```

And the new page tag:

```
#{StatusSelect id:'status1', name:'status', class:'bold'/}
```

Comment: I was trying to pass the values through the controller, this is much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to use Damo's approach with the enums name and then use the #{select}-tag of the framework.